# How to determine if a bell-shaped distribution is too skewed to be considered normal for use of the empirical rule and/or Z-score?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

We have such statistical tools for the normal distribution as the empirical rule and Z-score.
But in real life we frequently work with bell-shaped distributions that look kind of "normal", i.e. they are approximately normal. But how do we determine if a specific distribution is close enough to a normal distribution for use of such things as the empirical rule and Z-scores? What if, for example, the distribution is too skewed to the right/left?

I wonder if there is a formula or some kind rule of a thumb. I know only that both np>=5 and nq>=5 must be true if we want to approximate the binomial distribution through the normal distribution, but I don't know anything like this for applicability of the empirical rule and Z-score to an approximately normal distribution.

I ask it because I currently have a problem with my population, namely I want to apply the empirical rule and Z-score to it, but I'm afraid that it's too skewed.

Comment: What is your _goal_ in 'applying' the ER or using z-scores? Can you show one of your questionable datasets and explain what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: @BruceET Dataset:statistics of countries in Nationstates game. Goal: to make scoring method, so a country would add up its z-scores on its statistics, like Z-score for Safety(rate)+ Z-score for Integrity(rate), etc, so it would be possible to say that one country is better than another based on several parameters.
Like if would calculate the total score of a student, who passed through different exams, by summing up Z-score from each exam.

Comment: There's no magic rule, but the [QQ-plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%E2%80%93Q_plot) is a nice way to check visually if a distribution is normal-ish.

Comment: Using z-scores will put each 'rate' on a scale with mean 0 and SD 1, even if not exactly standard normally distributed. That may be good enough for your purposes. Maybe try z-scores for a few test cases and see if you think the idea is working. All attempts to rate which country is 'best' are subjective, so maybe your subjective opinion of results is all that matters. // I subscribe to a magazine that often tries to rate US cities according to various criteria (usually obscure). For my taste some pretty awful cities win some of these 'contests' and some wonderful ones are at the bottom.